# BRMS Giving error when importing repo.xml on other node

Tags: application, jboss

BRMS Version 5.3
Jboss 6.0
RHEL 6.4

I have installed BRMS 5.3 On RHEL 6.4 & was able to import the default repository successfully for the first time,  but I am unable to import UAT repository on another PROD system

When I am doing such implementation ether my system is getting hanged or its gives an error repo is to large

```
 Caused by: org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: repository
```